# Pop up box not appearing after adding ?ref

Tags: php, html, css

i am having an issue with my codes for a project i've been working on for the past few days..

```
<a  href='#popup1?QStrUId=<?php echo $row["emp_no"];?>'>
```

if i remove the "`?QStrUId=<?php echo $row["emp_no"];?>`" from the href tag, the popup works but if i add the previous line, the popup don't work..

Basically am trying to transfer the information `<?php echo $row["emp_no"];?>` to the pop up box so that i can continue forward using the emp_no and the popup is all css, no javascript or jquery has been used to open, display or close the pop up box.

Any idea about why this is happening?

Edit*
this is the popup box that should appear..

```
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
<div class="popup">
<h2>Employee Information</h2>
<a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
<div class="content">
    Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Link to the original codes which ive used.
https://codepen.io/imprakash/pen/GgNMXO

Comment: what popup?bootstrap ?

Comment: What code or script is supposed to make the pop up appear ?

Comment: ive updated the post and added a link from where ive got the codes and modified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to change id of your popup too. Your link id and popup id are different. That's a problem.

```
<div id="popup1?QStrUId=<?php echo $row["emp_no"];?>" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
    <h2>Employee Information</h2>
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <div class="content">
        Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this 
        window.
    </div>
</div>
```